# Getting Nil while testing Controller with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, rspec-rails

I´m trying to test my Controller in `Get Index` but i always recieve the Error 'got Nil'. This is my code for Spec:

```
 require 'rails_helper'


describe UsersController, :type => :controller do

   describe 'GET #index' do
   it 'populates an array of users' do
     user = create(:user)
     get :index
   expect(assigns(:users)).to eq([user])
 end
it 'renders the :index view' do
  get :index
  expect(response).to render_template(:index)
  end
end
```

This is my Controller:

```
def index
@users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

And this is my Factory for Users:

```
require 'faker'

  FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
     name      { Faker::Name.last_name }
     firstname { Faker::Name.first_name }
     email     { Faker::Internet.email }
     password  { Faker::Internet.password }
  end
end
```

Any Ideas why i receve this error? Is there anything special to add to my 'rails_helper' while testing controllers?

Comment: could you post the full error message?

Comment: i got the solution i needed to change this: 

      assigns(:user).should eq(@user)

Comment: ^That sounds really wrong. First of all you are using a local variable and not an instance variable. I'm guessing the error is that `.paginate` returns a object which fails the `.eq` equity check. Use an inclusion matcher instead. `expect(assigns(:users)).to include(user)`

Comment: But using `assigns`is a [flawed approach](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18950) and is depreciated in Rails 5.